# SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment: when is mandatory use RANDOM_PORT and DEFINED_PORT?

Tags: spring-boot

For `Spring Boot` for testing it works around with `@SpringBootTest` and together with the `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment` enum. Well, it has 4 values according with the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.html).

Futhermore I have read the [Testing Spring Boot Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications) section

For me is clear that `NONE` is to test just the server side and `MOCK` to test all server side with web side (to work around with `Spring MVC Test`). Until here I am ok. I use both.

The other two: `RANDOM_PORT` and `DEFINED_PORT` are related to `to start a full running server`, it according with the [Testing with a running server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server) section (First paragraph starting that section)

Two questions:

- In what scenario or scenarios is mandatory work with a `full running server`?
- What could the specific scenarios to use mandatorily either `RANDOM_PORT` or `DEFINED_PORT`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd typically use a full running server if you want to test your application as it will be used in production. With a full running server, you make HTTP requests to the server over a TCP network connection. This involves the network stack and servlet container in the test. By contrast, when you're using Spring MVC test, Spring Framework's `DispatcherServlet` is called directly with a mock request. The network stack and servlet container are not involved.

`DEFINED_PORT` means that your server will upon a TCP socket and listen for HTTP requests on a specific port. By default, it's 8080. If you're testing in an environment where you don't know if the specific port will be available, this an lead to test failures due to a port clash.

`RANDOM_PORT` means that your server will start on a port that's allocated by the operating system and is guaranteed to be available. Spring Boot makes this port available to your application by using the `@LocalServerPort` annotation on a field in your test class. It also auto-configures the default `TestRestTemplate` instance to use this port.

Comment: Thanks, about `With a full running server, you make HTTP requests to the server over a TCP network connection` It means I could use or test the app either  from the same app (no mock) or other project to call it. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use or test the app from anywhere that has network access to it.